# Split Larger String Into Console Window based on window size

Tags: c#

**Issue:**
Our application logs and traces are not standard, to help our aggregation tool for multiline content required some intervention on our part. Below I wrote some code to partition those longer strings into lines based on window size.  I feel like the code could be improved.

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Partition(this string content, int size)
{
     var index = 1;
     var line = String.Empty;

     var lines = new List<string>();
     var words = content.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

     foreach(var word in words)
     {
          if((line.Length + word.Length) <= size)
               line += $"{word} ";

          if((line.Length + word.Length + words.ElementAt(index).Length > 96)
          {
               lines.Add(line);
               line = String.Empty;
          }

          index++;
     }

     return lines;
}
```

The complaint or area that stands out:

- The excessive instantiation of string
- The collection and loop combination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest a simpler implementation. Instead of looking ahead in a second if-statement, we output the current line if adding the new word would exceed the maximum line size and clear the `StringBuilder` used to build the lines (see below). We ensure the last line is returned after the loop.

We use a [StringBuilder Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder) to minimize the number of string allocations. Also, we return the lines immediately by using an [iterator method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/yield). This makes the `List<string>` collection superfluous, which saves allocations again.

```cs
public static IEnumerable<string> Partition(this string content, int maxLineLength)
{
    string[] words = content.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var sb = new StringBuilder(maxLineLength + 1); // + 1 for the trailing white space.
    foreach (string word in words) {
        if (sb.Length > 0 && sb.Length + word.Length > maxLineLength) {
            sb.Length--; // Remove the trailing white space.
            yield return sb.ToString();
            sb.Clear();
        }
        sb.Append(word).Append(' ');
    }
    if (sb.Length > 1) {
        sb.Length--; // Remove the trailing white space.
        yield return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

I also tested for `sb.Length > 0` in the if-condition, just in case a single word exceeds the maximum line length.

Removing the trailing white spaces is an addition to your implementation.

Test

```cs
string input = "Issue: Our application logs and traces are not standard, to help our aggregation tool for multiline content required some intervention on our part. Below I wrote some code to partition those longer strings into lines based on window size. I feel like the code could be improved.";
foreach (string line in input.Partition(40)) {
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

outputs:

```
Issue: Our application logs and traces
are not standard, to help our
aggregation tool for multiline content
required some intervention on our part.
Below I wrote some code to partition
those longer strings into lines based on
window size. I feel like the code could
be improved.
```

---

A more advanced implementation could use a [ReadOnlySpan<char>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.readonlyspan-1) and the [MemoryExtensions.Split Method (.NET 8.0)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions.split) to save even more memory allocations.

Comment: I was not sure if the output would be large enough to consume the byte limit for the `StringBuilder` compared to the raw `String` but I do like the intent defined by the builder a bit more.   Could you not trim the white space on the `ToString` rather then decrement?

Comment: The `StringBuilder` has an internal buffer big enough, so that new words can be added without allocating memory each time. When the buffer is too small a bigger one will be allocated automatically. Decrementing the `Length` of the `StringBuilder` does not allocate any memory, unlike trimming a `string`, which does create and allocate a new `string` every time. Remember: strings are immutable. Every string operation allocates a new string!

Comment: I forgot the trim would create a new `String` to represent.  Yeah, I remember the `StringBuilder` buffer I just thought unless it was over 2048 in length the memory allocation is smaller for all those `string` versus the default allocation on the `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Also, trimming the string using `TrimEnd` will analyze the string to find any white space characters at the end of the string. This is not necessary, since know that there is exactly one white space there.